# How to get Access 2007 to run VBA subroutines when scrolling through records in a form

Tags: ms-access, vba, records

I have a series of "on Change" Enabled/Disabled subroutines in the VBA for a form.

When scrolling through the form to view records however, only the main routine runs--the subroutines don't. As a result, questions appear disbaled that have responses displayed.

How do I get the subroutines to run when a record is viewed/changed?

Answer (score 0):

The OnChange only fires when the relevant object is updated.  If you want code to run whenever the record is scrolled, put it in the form's OnCurrent event.

Answer (score 0):

I too have found Access form events to be a bit hard to work with/unpredictable.  One thing that worked for me is to use a label or textbox and set the Control Source to a formula or a call to my own VBA function to get what I need done.  Your control could also be invisible if it is not needed for the GUI.  I doubt this is best practice but this "simulated" event worked for me.

Comment: I too found the Access form and control events to be a bit tricky when I first started working with Access.  But now I generally only use about 3 or 4 of them and I like to think my apps run quite smoothly.

Comment: I try use standard events whenever they work but I used the ControlSource trick in a continuous form since as David mentioned above, the scrolling record events were not working out.

Answer (score 0):

If you need conditional presentation in a list, a continuous form and events are not going to do the job. In some cases CONDITIONAL FORMATTING will do the job, but only for appearance -- it can't do things like show/hide controls or alter the rowsource of dropdown lists or requery them.

Conceptually it would be impossible to do so. Form-level events fire for the record. Scrolling through the form does not move the record pointer.

I avoid using continuous forms for editing precisely because of this issue. Instead, I bind a detail subform to the PK value of the record selected in the continuous form, and then the detail form can do all the conditional formatting it needs to.